# Deslizar modal al presionar botón con Js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo el siguiente caso, quiero  que al presionar un botón me aparezca un modal deslizándose de arriba hacia bajo y para cerrarlo en viceversa, hasta el momento tengo el siguiente código pero no funciona.

```js
// Get the modal

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("INVENTARIO");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modal.slideDown.display = "slow"; //Código para deslizar modal
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 10px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 125%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  color: #000000;
  background-image: url(../IMAGENES/bg_ventana_modal.png);
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  height: 73%;
  border-radius: 12px;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h3>INVENTARIO DE VEHICULOS</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ALISTAMIENTO</th>
        <th>ESTADO</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="inventario">
          <font face="arial" size="1">PINTURA</font>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <select name="PINTURA" id="PINTURA">
                          <option value="Seleccione...">Seleccione...</option>
                          <option value="BUENO">BUENO</option>
                          <option value="MALO">MALO</option>
                          <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                      </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>


<input type="button" name="INVENTARIO" id="INVENTARIO" value="Insertar" onclick="document.getElementById('id01')">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: black;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    /* The Modal (background) */
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
  <button id="myBtn">Insertar</button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>VEHICULOS</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>INVENTARIO DE VEHICULOS</h3>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>ALISTAMIENTO</th>
            <th>ESTADO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="inventario">
              <font face="arial" size="1">PINTURA</font>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
              <select name="PINTURA" id="PINTURA">
                          <option value="Seleccione...">Seleccione...</option>
                          <option value="BUENO">BUENO</option>
                          <option value="MALO">MALO</option>
                          <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                      </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <h3>fINAL</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {  
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```